# Getting an error when calling an activity when making an outgoing call action in android

Tags: android

I m creating an app in which user will call an entered number and when that number picks up the call it automatically displays a screen in which four navigation keys are shown.

Basically i m trying to run a micro controller using DTMF through android. 
I don't know much about android. Please help me with this error.

These are the classes which i have defined for this app.

MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

final Context context = this;
private Button button;
private EditText edit;
String number;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.call);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    number = "tel:" + edit.getText().toString().trim();
    // add PhoneStateListener
    PhoneCallListener phoneListener = new PhoneCallListener();
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) this
        .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    telephonyManager.listen(phoneListener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse(number));
            startActivity(callIntent);

        }

    });

}

//monitor phone call activities
private class PhoneCallListener extends PhoneStateListener {

    private boolean isPhoneCalling = false;

    String LOG_TAG = "LOGGING 123";

    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING == state) {
            // phone ringing
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "RINGING, number: " + incomingNumber);
        }

        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state) {
            // active
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "OFFHOOK");

            isPhoneCalling = true;

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, DtmfActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE == state) {
            // run when class initial and phone call ended, 
            // need detect flag from CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "IDLE");

            if (isPhoneCalling) {

                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "restart app");

                // restart app
                Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
                    .getLaunchIntentForPackage(
                        getBaseContext().getPackageName());
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);

                isPhoneCalling = false;
            }

        }
    }
  }

}
```

DtmfActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.ToneGenerator;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import static android.media.ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_2;
import static android.media.ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_4;
import static android.media.ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_6;
import static android.media.ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_8;

public class DtmfActivity extends Activity{

public Button up, dwn, left, right;
static final ToneGenerator _toneGenerator = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100);

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    up = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    left = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    right = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    dwn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);

    up.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            _toneGenerator.startTone(TONE_DTMF_2);
            _toneGenerator.stopTone();
        }
    });

    left.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            _toneGenerator.startTone(TONE_DTMF_4);
            _toneGenerator.stopTone();
        }
    });

    right.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            _toneGenerator.startTone(TONE_DTMF_6);
            _toneGenerator.stopTone();
        }
    });

    dwn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            _toneGenerator.startTone(TONE_DTMF_8);
            _toneGenerator.stopTone();
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Manifest

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <receiver android:name=".PhoneStateReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
        </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name="com.ziindia.dtmf.DtmfActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.project.dtmf.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

And logcat details

```
07-09 13:33:53.990: I/LOGGING 123(1153): OFFHOOK
07-09 13:33:54.200: D/AndroidRuntime(1153): Shutting down VM
07-09 13:33:54.200: W/dalvikvm(1153): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3a5dba8)
07-09 13:33:54.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1153): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-09 13:33:54.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1153): Process: com.project.dtmf, PID: 1153
07-09 13:33:54.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1153): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.project.dtmf/com.project.dtmf.DtmfActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
07-09 13:33:54.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1153):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
07-09 13:33:54.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1153):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
07-09 13:33:54.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1153):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
07-09 13:33:54.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1153):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)
07-09 13:33:54.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1153):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3627)
07-09 13:33:54.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1153):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3595)
07-09 13:33:54.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1153):     at com.project.dtmf.MainActivity$PhoneCallListener.onCallStateChanged(MainActivity.java:75)
07-09 13:33:54.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1153):     at android.telephony.PhoneStateListener$2.handleMessage(PhoneStateListener.java:369)
07-09 13:33:54.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1153):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-09 13:33:54.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1153):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-09 13:33:54.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1153):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
07-09 13:33:54.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1153):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-09 13:33:54.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1153):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-09 13:33:54.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1153):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
07-09 13:33:54.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1153):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
07-09 13:33:54.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1153):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-09 13:33:58.290: I/Process(1153): Sending signal. PID: 1153 SIG: 9
```

I dont understand why i m getting this error 
when i have defined every thing properly in my best knowledge
Someone plz help me
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at the error? It tells you exactly what is wrong: `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.project.dtmf/com.project.dtmf.DtmfActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?`

Comment: Yes i have looked that error but i dont know how to resolve this. I have searched may other posts but didnt find any solution for this. Plz help me if you know where i m doing wrong

Comment: See my answer for more details.

Comment: I have edited my answer with further details, I hope I could help you!

Comment: Yes i saw it. Changing my code. Hope it will help. Thanx.

Comment: I'm glad I could help! Please don't forget to accept my answer if it helped you out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error tells you exactly what is wrong:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.project.dtmf/com.project.dtmf.DtmfActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

You mixed up you package names. Look at your manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.ziindia.dtmf.DtmfActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

Do you see it? `com.ziindia.dtmf.DtmfActivity` should be `com.project.dtmf.DtmfActivity`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your project's dierctory structure.At the first look from the log it seems your calling an invalid intent. Soit may be because in your manifest file, two activities uses different 
directory structure. make sure that you are using the correct qualified name.

```
<activity
            android:name="com.**ziindia**.dtmf.DtmfActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.**project**.dtmf.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

Comment: Yeah i saw that.
My code is now working
Thanx :-)

Actually com.ziindia.dtmf was my earlier package name
I renamed it to com.project.dtmf and i think eclipse missed to rename it here.